# Calling a function with double parameters () in javascript

Tags: javascript

Anyone know what happens when you call a function with double ()

so

```
get_separate_save_methods_function(url, false);
```

becomes

```
get_separate_save_methods_function(url, false)();
```

I've never seen this before but it seems to change the false argument to true, when you remove the extra () the same argument becomes false. It's not my code and I'm just trying to work out if this is a mistake or has been done of purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `()` doesn't change the argument from `false` to `true`.

```
get_separate_save_methods_function(url, false)();
```

can be used when

```
get_separate_save_methods_function(url, false)
```

returns a function. It calls this returned function.

Given the `get_separate_save_methods_function` name, this is probably not a mistake but it's hard to tell more with just this code.

Answer (score 0):

If `get_seperate_save_methods_function(url, false)` **returns** a function itself, then the extra set of parantheses on the end will immediately execute the function that's been returned.